# What does count(*)=1 do?

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle

```
SELECT 
    AL1.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD, 
    AL1.BUSINESS_AREA, 
    AL1.SAP_ACCOUNT, 
    AL1.ID, 
    AL1.USD_AMT, 
    AL1.BAN_NBR, 
    AL2.CUST_NBR, 
    AL2.CUST_NAME
FROM
    DSL_AIM.AIM AL1,
    DSL_AML.AID AL2 
WHERE
    (
        (
            AL1.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD_CD IN ( '2023-02' )

GROUP BY
    AL1.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD,
    AL1.BUSINESS_AREA,
    AL1.SAP_ACCOUNT,
    AL1.ID,
    AL1.USD_AMT,
    AL1.BAN_NBR,
    AL2.CUST_NBR,
    AL2.CUST_NAME

HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 1;
```

I get a different amount of line items when I have the having statement and when I don't, so what does `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` mean/do in this context?

Comment: Your SQL is invalid: your `WHERE` clause has unbalanced parentheses; 3x `(` but only 1x `)` - and using `GROUP BY` with non-key columns is a code-smell (if not an outright antipattern): for best results only `GROUP BY` _meaningful_ columns and then `INNER JOIN` with the base tables to get non-aggregate data.

Comment: [**HAVING Clause**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2182483)
*Use the HAVING clause to restrict the groups of returned rows to those groups for which the specified condition is TRUE. If you omit this clause, then the database returns summary rows for all groups.*

Comment: Also, you should use an explicit `JOIN`, as right now you're using a Cartesian Product of your two tables, which is a pain to deal with.

Comment: You could put count(*) into the select and see what it comes up with..

Comment: MySQL and Oracle are two different DBMS. Which are you using? Comma joins are out-dated. For the last thirty years we have been using explicit joins instead (e.g. `FROM dsl_aim.aim al1 INNER JOIN dsl_aml.aid al2 ON al2.ida = al1.idb`).

Answer (score 5):

> what does `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` mean/do in this context?

It returns all the rows where there is not a duplicate with the same values.

For example, given the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (x, y, z) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 4, 5 FROM DUAL;
```

Then the similar query:

```
SELECT x, y, z
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY x, y, z
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Outputs:

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |

The `2, 2, 2` row is not included as there are two instances of the row and so `COUNT(*) = 2` and not `1` for that group; the other rows are included as they are all unique.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/e0V2Yv4q)

Answer (score 2):

Query seems to be wrong altogether; there's **no join** between tables so you're producing Cartesian product, and then filter it on accounting period. Besides, `where` clause doesn't require parenthesis, and you have two of them here: `where ((` which aren't closed.

---

```
SELECT 
AL1.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD, 
AL1.BUSINESS_AREA, 
AL1.SAP_ACCOUNT, 
AL1.ID, 
AL1.USD_AMT, 
AL1.BAN_NBR, 
AL2.CUST_NBR, 
AL2.CUST_NAME
COUNT(*)                                   --> add this
FROM DSL_AIM.AIM AL1, DSL_AML.AID AL2 
WHERE ((AL1.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD_CD IN ('2023-02')
GROUP BY AL1.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD, AL1.BUSINESS_AREA, AL1.SAP_ACCOUNT, AL1.ID, AL1.USD_AMT, AL1.BAN_NBR, AL2.CUST_NBR, AL2.CUST_NAME
```

you'd see number of rows that share the same set of values in all non-aggregated columns (i.e. all columns specified in `GROUP BY` clause).

Then, you can add the `HAVING` clause to further *filter* result set. In your case, it is `having count(*) = 1`, which means that there's only one row per combination.

It could have been e.g. `having count(*) > 1`, which means that you'd fetch rows that represent "duplicates".

Comment: That helps a lot. I added a Join statement to fix things! Thank you so much for your help!